# My dynamic content is not working in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm new to React and currently facing an issue in my application. I have a component derived from a template that I'm converting to JSX. To incorporate existing JavaScript logic, I've placed it within a useEffect. However, I've encountered a problem where a specific div element within a mapping operation isn't functioning correctly, whereas the same div outside the mapping operation is working as expected. I'm uncertain about the suitability of my approach, which involves using querySelectors and direct DOM manipulation within React. I'm seeking assistance to resolve this issue.

Please tell me if there is any library in React for same filter effects.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Isotope from "isotope-layout";
import { initializeAOS } from "../../../utils/initializeAOS";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "../../../store";
import { fetchPortfolio } from "../../../services/portfolioSrevice";

type LayoutModes =
  | "masonry"
  | "fitRows"
  | "vertical"
  | "cellsByRow"
  | "packery"
  | "masonryHorizontal"
  | "fitColumns"
  | "horiz";

const PortfolioPage = () => {
  const portfolioIsotopeRef = useRef<Isotope | null>(null);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { PortfolioLoading, Portfoliodata } = useAppSelector(
    (state) => state.portfolio
  );
  console.log(Portfoliodata);
  useEffect(() => {
    const initializeIsotope = () => {
      const portfolionIsotope = document.querySelector(".portfolio-isotope");

      if (portfolionIsotope) {
        const portfolioFilter =
          portfolionIsotope.getAttribute("data-portfolio-filter") || "*";
        const portfolioLayout =
          (portfolionIsotope.getAttribute(
            "data-portfolio-layout"
          ) as LayoutModes) || "masonry";
        const portfolioSort =
          portfolionIsotope.getAttribute("data-portfolio-sort") ||
          "original-order";

        const container = document.querySelector(
          ".portfolio-container"
        ) as HTMLElement;

        if (container) {
          portfolioIsotopeRef.current = new Isotope(container, {
            itemSelector: ".portfolio-item",
            layoutMode: portfolioLayout,
            filter: portfolioFilter as
              | string
              | ((itemElement: HTMLElement) => boolean),
            sortBy: portfolioSort,
          });

          const menuFilters = document.querySelectorAll(
            ".portfolio-isotope .portfolio-flters li"
          );
          menuFilters.forEach((el) => {
            el.addEventListener("click", handleFilterClick);
          });

          const allFilterButton = document.querySelector(
            '.portfolio-flters li[data-filter="*"]'
          ) as HTMLButtonElement;
          if (allFilterButton) {
            allFilterButton.click();
          }
        }
      }
    };

    const handleFilterClick = (event: Event) => {
      const el = event.target as HTMLElement;
      const activeFilter = document.querySelector(
        ".portfolio-isotope .portfolio-flters .filter-active"
      );
      activeFilter?.classList.remove("filter-active");
      el.classList.add("filter-active");

      if (portfolioIsotopeRef.current) {
        portfolioIsotopeRef.current.arrange({
          filter: el.getAttribute("data-filter") || "",
        });
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        initializeAOS();
      }, 200);
    };

    dispatch(fetchPortfolio());
    const cleanup = () => {
      if (portfolioIsotopeRef.current) {
        portfolioIsotopeRef.current.destroy();
      }

      const menuFilters = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".portfolio-isotope .portfolio-flters li"
      );
      menuFilters.forEach((el) => {
        el.removeEventListener("click", handleFilterClick);
      });

      window.removeEventListener("load", initializeIsotope);
      window.removeEventListener("load", initializeAOS);
    };

    // Initialize Isotope and AOS when the component mounts
    initializeIsotope();
    window.addEventListener("load", initializeAOS);

    return cleanup;
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="page-portfolio">
      <main id="main">
        <div
          className="breadcrumbs d-flex align-items-center"
          style={{
            backgroundImage:
              "url('static/template/assets/img/portfolio-header.jpg')",
          }}
        >
          <div className="container position-relative d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
            <h2>Portfolio</h2>
            <ol>
              <li>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>Portfolio</li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>

        <section id="portfolio" className="portfolio">
          <div className="container" data-aos="fade-up">
            <div
              className="portfolio-isotope"
              data-portfolio-filter="*"
              data-portfolio-layout="masonry"
              data-portfolio-sort="original-order"
            >
              <ul
                className="portfolio-flters"
                data-aos="fade-up"
                data-aos-delay="100"
              >
                 **{Portfoliodata?.map((data) => (
                  <li
                    data-filter={
                      data.category.name === "All"
                        ? "*"
                        : `.filter-${data.category.name}`
                    }
                  >
                    {data.category.name}
                  </li>
                ))}** 

                **<li data-filter="*">ALL</li>
                <li data-filter=".filter-app">Branding</li>
                <li data-filter=".filter-Books">Books</li>
              </ul>**
              <div
                className="row gy-4 portfolio-container"
                data-aos="fade-up"
                data-aos-delay="300"
              >
                **{Portfoliodata?.map(() => (
                  <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app">
                    <img
                      src="static/template/assets/img/portfolio/app-1.jpg"
                      className="img-fluid"
                      alt=""
                    />
                    <div className="portfolio-info">
                      <h4>App 1</h4>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur</p>
                      <a
                        href="static/template/assets/img/portfolio/app-1.jpg"
                        title="App 1"
                        // data-gallery="portfolio-gallery-app"
                        className="preview-link"
                      >
                        <i className="bi bi-zoom-in"></i>
                      </a>
                      <a
                        href="portfolio-details.html"
                        title="More Details"
                        className="details-link"
                      >
                        <i className="bi bi-link-45deg"></i>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
                <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app">
                  <img
                    src="static/template/assets/img/portfolio/app-1.jpg"
                    className="img-fluid"
                    alt=""
                  />
                  <div className="portfolio-info">
                    <h4>App 1</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur</p>
                    <a
                      href="static/template/assets/img/portfolio/app-1.jpg"
                      title="App 1"
                      // data-gallery="portfolio-gallery-app"
                      className="preview-link"
                    >
                      <i className="bi bi-zoom-in"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a
                      href="portfolio-details.html"
                      title="More Details"
                      className="details-link"
                    >
                      <i className="bi bi-link-45deg"></i>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>**
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {PortfolioLoading && <div id="preloader"></div>}
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PortfolioPage;
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem a bit more and narrow down the code you provided to isolate the problem? My guess is that if you do the latter, you'll find the issue but as it stands, it's hard to be sure what your problem actually is.

Comment: the problem is that I have a portfolio Page and here my static content is working like there is a list of categories. This list when static works fine but when this list of categories is coming from backend through APIs and when I map this it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

check the **Portfoliodata** property.
it could have , data property which hold array.

```js
const {data,isLoading,isSuccess} = Portfoliodata;

data?.map((portfolio) => (
                  <li
                    data-filter={
                      portfolio.category.name === "All"
                        ? "*"
                        : `.filter-${portfolio.category.name}`
                    }
                  >
                    {portfolio.category.name}
                  </li>
                )
```

Comment: actually Portfoliodata holds the array and it is shwoing data in console...